# What kind of sorting does the Windows 7 login screen use for usernames?

Tags: windows-7, login, user-accounts

I’ve set up ten Windows 7 user accounts, so that I can test different versions of Google Chrome*. I’ve named the accounts “Chrome 01”, “Chrome 02”, and so on.

Ideally, I’d like the accounts sorted on the login screen by Chrome version, which is why I added the leading zero to the version number (assuming it was an alphabetic sort). However, when I created the “Chrome 10” account, it ended up sorted between “Chrome 01” and “Chrome 02”.

What is going on?

<sub>*(Chrome installs [are user-account-specific](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785991/can-i-run-multiple-versions-of-google-chrome-on-the-same-machine-mac-or-windows/3786165#3786165))</sub>

Comment: What ther smeg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Names on the logon screen are sorted alphabetically by the account's name *when the account was created*. So, if you rename `Chrome 01` to `Chrome 10`, it will stay in `01`'s position on the login screen, because internally, it is still `Chrome 01`; only the display name has changed.

I just tested on a Windows 7 VM and when I created accounts `SU Test 01`, `02`, `04`, `03`, and `10` (in that order), it listed them in proper alphabetic order, as `01`, `02`, `03`, `04`, `10`. The most likely explanation is that you tried renaming an account that was previously between 1 and 2, and so it is staying in that position.

Comment: Doh! Yes, that’s exactly what I did (because, like an idiot, I created Chrome 1 — Chrome 9 before realising I’d need a Chrome 10). Oh dear. The less-than-ideal ordering might be something I learn to live with.

Comment: Why not add a Chrome 0 instead and solve both problems?

Comment: @passcod: I think I’d still have the same problems regarding the “incorrect” positioning of my existing 1—9 user accounts relative to the forthcoming Chrome 11, 12 etc. accounts.